# Using TrueCrypt with File Replication on Windows Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, truecrypt, replication, dfs

We have a few folders that are set to replicate to a DR file server off-site. One of these folders contains a file that is a TrueCrypt volume container.

When this file is mounted in TrueCrypt, the file won't replicate (fair enough!).

I'm looking at alternatives to improve this situation.

One solution I currently have is to have a scheduled task to unmount the volume and then every morning as the volume is needed, have someone mount it. This is a pain slightly because the password is known by a few people (I'm not one and neither are my colleagues who would be performing the mounting operation) so we'd need to continually get them to come over and type it in.

The other I had was to have one TrueCrypt container on each server and replicate the contents when they are mounted. I wasn't able to get TrueCrypt to see the mounted volume so I guess this is a no go.

Any other solutions I have missed or a fix for the above?

Comment: Can you set up File replication to use [VSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Copy)? Also you may get a better result on ServerFault.com, this is more of a IT question than a power user question. You can flag your own question for a moderator and they can move it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Strange that I came across this question, after reading [this](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=sharing-over-network) article only two days ago. Provided a lot of insights for me, and cleared up some issues I had with networking a TC volume.

Comment: We prefer you to include at least a summary rather just linking to an article elsewhere. Links can and will die.